# Laravel how to prevent href link gets appended with current url

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Let's say my project root is http://localhost/laravel-project

In the project I have navigation menu, the sample format of the link is
`<a href="home">home</a>"`
So when I click the link the url on my browser is `http://localhost/laravel-project/home`

I do not know why if I have another link 
`<a href="invoice/show/1">home</a>"` and the route is `Route::get('/invoice/show/{id}', 'Frontend\CommonController@show');`

when I click the link, the previous home link will become
`http://localhost/laravel-project/invoice/show/member` it's supposed to be `http://localhost/laravel-project/home`.

The inside show method :

```
public function show(){

        return view('frontend.invoice', ['subaccounts' => $this->subaccounts, 'menus' => $this->menus]);
    }
```

I have tested it, the cause of the problem is the segments on the link `invoice/show/1` if the link is only `invoice` then everything is fine.

Anyone knows what is wrong and how to solve this issue ?

Note : I am using a blade template

Comment: can you show what is inside Frontend\CommonController@show method?

Comment: Updated my question. The action simply returns a view with data.

Comment: it does not seem to be php or laravel issue. its simple HTML you have shared. Can you verify if both views i.e. first page and frontend.invoice have same menu bar html.

Comment: Yes I can guarantee that because I use the same template for both

Comment: Route::get('home/invoice/show/{id}', 'Frontend\CommonController@show'); and the link <a href="home/invoice/show/1">home</a>"

Comment: No..that is not how I want to solve the problem. I would like to know how to prevent the `<a>` tag url gets appended with the current url on browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using the function `{{url('linkName')}}` in the link.